# Why can't I authenticate my SSH connection? Credentials and keygen both not working

Tags: networking, ssh, mathematica

I'm writing a bit confused because I've tried everything. Let me know if I'm missing any critical information for you to help me.

I'm trying to SSH into my Cyberpower PDU (device probably not important), which is connected to my computer running Windows 10 via Ethernet cable. I have enabled SSH communication on the device by logging into the IP address that I set it up on and configuring my port 22 for SSH. I need to use Mathematica for this project, so that's what I've been using.

At first I thought that simply telling Mathematica to connect to the IP address of my device and entering my computer log-in credentials would work, because that's how you usually SSH into your server. Mathematica kept returning an error that my credentials were wrong, even though they weren't.

So then I tried using a keygen, which should be foolproof. Even when I generate a private key and tell Mathematica to use that file to connect to SSH, it still asks me for my computer log-in credentials, which it shouldn't! Because the SSH key should be enough. And then I enter my credentials and it still won't let me in.

I don't expect many Mathematica users here, but here's my code below. This should be enough to establish the connection. (and ignore the fact that my SSH key is stored under a different user's folder - my computer wasn't wiped properly before being administered to me. I also disguised my IP address.)

`RemoteConnect[IPAddress["XXX.XXX.XX.XX"], Authentication -> <|"Username" -> "Darren", "SSHKey" -> File["C:\\Users\\chigozie\\.ssh\\id_rsa"]|>]`

I should add that when I use PuTTY to do the same thing, my credentials work... but when I use Powershell, they don't. It's gotta be some permissions issue but I don't have the know-how yet to know where to start in troubleshooting that.

Generally speaking what could be the reasons why I get rejected from of my SSH network even when I'm using a private key and entering my correct credentials? What should I do to solve those issues?

Thanks!!!

Comment: "ignore the fact that my SSH key is stored under a different user's folder" - You realize by the key being in the incorrect location, it most likely, has the incorrect permissions and cannot be used.

Comment: what if you try to ssh outside of mathematica with your username and password. from a linux box I would ask you to use `ssh -vvv` options to see the output. if it says your credentials are invalid, most often it is. does the user Darren exist on the device where you enabled ssh?

Comment: You mention that you've created a key pair... but did you ever upload the public key to the PDU?

Comment: @user1686 you know, what's weird is that the PDU only lets upload my private key file to it, not my public key. Then it spits back a Hostkey fingerprint to verify, which I'm looking into now

Comment: @Ramhound yeah i know that seems like an obvious caveat - but I've been copying the private keys to my own user folder and trying that out as well. my computer automatically defaults to saving to that user's folder even though that user account has been deleted, which is annoying.

Comment: @Zina  Linux box? My PC only runs windows. Yes I've tried to SSH in from Powershell and ran into essentially the same problem. The user account Darren is the one I'm on, yes

Comment: I am currently not on my windows machine, didn't use ssh from powershell but I suppose it has a verbose option. and my question was if you have the user which you want to connect with on the PDU, not familiar with those either - but want to be sure that the user is there.

Comment: @Darren: That sounds like you're confusing user keys with host keys, then. They work similarly but in opposite directions. If the PDU doesn't actually have a feature to accept user keys in the first place, then no amount of key generation will help with that..

Comment: @user1686 ah, yes i was. alrighty, I will figure out a way to shove my user public key in its face so I can finally tunnel into it.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to Mathematica. Turns out the function they use for SSH tunneling is still an "experimental" function that they're working on. I'm able to do this tunneling from other programs so I'm just left to assume that it's a Mathematica problem :/